Verifying Math behind Full Bundle Adjustment for Multi-Camera Extrinsic Calibration
I'm working on an extrinsic calibration problem involving multiple monocular cameras. Each camera has known intrinsic parameters, and I have captured timestamp-aligned images of a calibration target from these cameras. The calibration target may sometimes go out of view. My goal is to compute the extrinsic parameters (rotation and translation) for each camera using bundle adjustment, given these knowns.
Problem Setup

Intrinsic Parameters ($\mathbf{K}_i$):
Each camera $i$ has a known intrinsic matrix:
$$
   \mathbf{K}_i = \begin{pmatrix}
   f_x & 0 & c_x \\
   0 & f_y & c_y \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

Extrinsic Parameters ($\mathbf{R}_i, \mathbf{t}_i$):
The rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}_i$ and translation vector $\mathbf{t}_i$ describe the orientation and position of camera $i$ in the world coordinate system.

3D Points ($\mathbf{P}_j$):
The 3D coordinates of the calibration target points in the world coordinate system.

Observed 2D Points ($\mathbf{u}_{ij}$):
The 2D image coordinates of the calibration target points detected in the images from camera $i$.


Bundle Adjustment Problem
The goal is to minimize the reprojection error, which is the difference between the observed 2D points and the projected 3D points of the calibration target.
Projection Function

Transform 3D World Coordinates to Camera Coordinates:
$$
   \mathbf{P}_{camera} = \mathbf{R}_i \mathbf{P}_j + \mathbf{t}_i
   $$

Project Camera Coordinates to Image Plane:
$$
   \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{K}_i \mathbf{P}_{camera} = \begin{pmatrix}
   f_x X_{camera} / Z_{camera} + c_x \\
   f_y Y_{camera} / Z_{camera} + c_y \\
   1
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$

Normalize Homogeneous Coordinates to Obtain Projected 2D Point:
$$
   \mathbf{u}_{proj} = \left(\frac{p_x}{p_z}, \frac{p_y}{p_z}\right) = \left(\frac{f_x X_{camera}}{Z_{camera}} + c_x, \frac{f_y Y_{camera}}{Z_{camera}} + c_y\right)
   $$


Cost Function
`The cost function to minimize is the sum of squared differences between the observed 2D points and the projected 2D points:
$$
\text{Cost} = \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \left\| \mathbf{u}_{ij} - \mathbf{u}_{proj} \right\|^2
$$
where $\mathbf{u}_{ij}$ is the observed 2D point of the calibration target corner $j$ in image $i$.$\mathbf{u}_{proj}$ is the projected 2D point calculated using the projection function $\pi(\cdot)$.`
Questions

Initialization:
How should I initialize the extrinsic parameters and the 3D coordinates of the calibration target points for the bundle adjustment to converge effectively?

Depth Handling:
Since all my cameras are monocular, is there any specific strategy to handle the depth of each point during the optimization, or does the bundle adjustment process take care of this implicitly?

Robustness:
Are there any best practices to improve the robustness of the bundle adjustment, such as handling outliers or ensuring better convergence?

Getting 3D points of calibration target
How do I get the 3D points of the calibration target? And in what frame of reference are they? For example if I am using a checkerboard, are the 3D points expressed in the body-fixed frame of reference of the checkerboard, so essentially these values never change?


